# Is it possible to change the timeout of Bluetooth Pairing Request with CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to know if is possible to change the timeout of alert popup of "Bluetooth Pairing Request". I couldn't find anything related to this.

[image: Bluetooth Pairing Request]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly the pairing process is completely controlled by iOS. There is no setting or parameter you could change.

Comment: I made a long research and there is no way to do that. Thanks for confirmation!

Comment: Any document which states it?. Is so could you pls provide the link?

Comment: @MasterStroke As there is no public API to do that, this is not a supported operation. You may be able to find private APIs but those cannot be used in App Store apps.