# BT Pairing Request default timeout?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have to set a timeout for the bluetooth pairing request if it's not accepted or canceled !!

```
It's mentioned that i have to use the timeout defined by Bluetooth standard   
I am searching for that in the internet but I found nothing 
I found this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674532/is-it-possible-to-change-the-timeout-of-bluetooth-pairing-request-with-corebluet1] and it's mentioned that pairing request timeout is not changeable ,
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timeout should be 30 seconds and is defined in the Security Manager Specification (Bluetooth Core Specification, Version 5.2, Vol 3, Part H, Section 3.4 SMP TIMEOUT):-

> To protect the Security Manager protocol from stalling, a Security
> Manager Timer is used. Upon transmission of the Security Request
> command or reception of the Security Request command, the Security
> Manager Timer shall be reset and restarted. Upon transmission of the
> Pairing Request command or reception of the Pairing Request command,
> the Security Manager Timer shall be reset and started.
>
> The Security Manager Timer shall be reset when an L2CAP SMP command is
> queued for transmission.
>
> When a Pairing process completes, the Security Manager Timer shall be
> stopped.
>
> If the Security Manager Timer reaches 30 seconds, the procedure shall
> be considered to have failed, and the local higher layer shall be
> notified. No further SMP commands shall be sent over the L2CAP
> Security Manager Channel. A new Pairing process shall only be
> performed when a new physical link has been established.

This is usually hardcoded in the stack/API, so maybe it is not something you have to set in your app.